# Process CSV file through command line: Remove only middle rows between consecutive row entries if consecutive entries have the same 2nd column value

Tags: text-processing, command-line, csv

I have a CSV file with only 2 columns (but *lots* of rows) and the occasional irregular row which always starts with an asterisk (*) character and may span more than two columns. Using just the Linux command line, the intended behavior is:

1. If 3 or more consecutive data rows have the same value for column two, delete the middle rows. Start and end rows are retained.
2. Retain the irregular rows that begin with an asterisk

For example, if I have a CSV with this content:

```
    0,Apple
    1,Apple
    2,Apple
    * Checkpoint
    * Another checkpoint
    3,Apple
    4,Apple
    5,Box
    6,Box
    7,Citrus
    8,Box
    9,Apple
    10,Apple
    11,Apple
    12,Dove
    13,Citrus
    * Sudden checkpoint, * Leftover checkpoint note 1, * Leftover checkpoint note N
    14,Citrus
    15,Citrus
    16,Citrus
    17,Apple
    18,Citrus
```

It should look like below after:

```
    0,Apple
    * Checkpoint
    * Another checkpoint
    4,Apple
    5,Box
    6,Box
    7,Citrus
    8,Box
    9,Apple
    11,Apple
    12,Dove
    13,Citrus
    * Sudden checkpoint, * Leftover checkpoint note 1, * Leftover checkpoint note N
    16,Citrus
    17,Apple
    18,Citrus
```

In the example above, lines 1 to 3, 10, and 14 to 15 were removed.

Thank you very much in advance for any answers.

Cheers

Comment: Why is line 11 removed?

Comment: Because its between line 10 and 13 which have "Citrus" on the 2nd column. The irregular rows starting with the asterisk do not count.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```c
BEGIN { FS = "," }

/^[*]/ { print; next }

{
        if (NR > 1 && $2 == word) {
                tail = $0
                ++count
        } else {
                if (count) print tail
                word = $2; count = 0
                print
        }
}

END { if (count) print tail }
```

This `awk` script unconditionally prints all lines that start with `*`.  If the line is not such a line, and if the word in the second field is a word that we have remembered, store the record in the variable `tail` ("tail" as in the last record of a run of records with the same word in the second field).

If the second field is *not* the same as in the previous, then print the tail record if there were more than one record in the previous run of records, then remember the new word and print the current record (the first record in a new run of one or more records with the same word in the second field).

Testing it on the data provided and assuming it is *simple CSV* (meaning no embedded delimiters or newlines etc.):

```bash
$ awk -f script file
0,Apple
* Checkpoint
* Another checkpoint
4,Apple
5,Box
6,Box
7,Citrus
8,Box
9,Apple
11,Apple
12,Dove
13,Citrus
* Sudden checkpoint, * Leftover checkpoint note 1, * Leftover checkpoint note N
16,Citrus
17,Apple
18,Citrus
```

---

Similar to the above but using [Miller (`mlr`)](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is CSV-aware and would be able to handle CSV records with complex quoted strings:

```bash
if (is_not_null(@word) && $2 == @word) {
        @tail = $*;
        false # omit this record for now
} else {
        is_not_null(@tail) {
                emit @tail # emit the tail record
        }
        @word = $2; @tail = null;
        true  # emit this record
}

end { is_not_null(@tail) { emit @tail } }
```

This is an expression for Miller's `filter` sub-command to include or omit records from the input data set using very similar logic to the `awk` code above.  We can make Miller pass through the lines starting with the character `*` by using `--pass-comments-with='*'` on the command line.  Using `--csv` with `-N` treats the input as header-less CSV.

```bash
$ mlr --pass-comments-with='*' --csv -N filter -f script file
0,Apple
* Checkpoint
* Another checkpoint
4,Apple
5,Box
6,Box
7,Citrus
8,Box
9,Apple
11,Apple
12,Dove
13,Citrus
* Sudden checkpoint," * Leftover checkpoint note 1"," * Leftover checkpoint note N"
16,Citrus
17,Apple
18,Citrus
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One thing though -- if I have, say, the first 5 rows containing `0,Apple` up to `4,Apple`, it seems to delete the first four rows as well, leaving only `4,Apple` as the start of the processed text. Would it be possible to retain the first data row? For the example just now, the first two rows will be, `0,Apple` followed by `4,Apple`

Comment: @CarlaH. I can not reproduce that behaviour with the code from my answer. Please check to see that what you are using is the same as I have written.

Comment: @CarlaH. what is "it" in the statement "it seems to delete..." - the awk script or the mlr script?

Comment: Its the `awk` script. Unfortunately, I am unable to test the `mlr` script yet as the off-grid linux workstation does not have it, and I have no admin/root access.

Comment: I've edited the example on the question. Again, thank you so much for this.

Comment: @CarlaH. I have updated the answer with the result of running the existing code on your updated data. No changes to the code were made as it appears to do the correct thing.

Comment: @CarlaH. I noticed that the `awk` code (but not Miller) would misbehave if the first few (more than one) record's 2nd field was _empty_. This was however not the case in the data that you provided (original or updated), but I have nevertheless corrected for this in the answer. This also makes the two solutions (`awk` and Miller) more similar.

Comment: The OPs posted sample input starts each row with white space, if that's real then that could cause the OP to see different output than you do and then you'd need to change `/^[*]/` to `/^[[:space:]]*[*]/` or `$1 ~ /^[*]/` or similar.

Comment: @CarlaH. check your input file for CRs at the end of some lines (see [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) ) as It's impossible for Kusalananda's original or updated script to behave as [you say it did](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/753232/process-csv-file-through-command-line-remove-only-middle-rows-between-consecuti/753247#comment1433543_753247) given your original or new sample input but a CR at the end of the first lines could explain your thought.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda and Ed, the `awk` script output is now ok. Thank you very much for helping me out!